# What is it about this albatross photograph that makes it look like it might either be faked or actually a photorealistic drawing (to me at least)?

Tags: photoshop, focus, contrast

When I first saw this photo of three albatross, it seemed wrong to me somehow - like the birds were hand-drawn and added to a photo of a background. It doesn't look like an actual photograph, but I can not say what it is exactly that is giving me that feeling, except perhaps mismatches in contrast and focus in different parts of the photo.

It is from Science Magazine's December 5, 2015 This Week in Science's [Not enough protection for migrating birds](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.2015.350.6265.twis) and it is a file photo (see the caption & credit under the photo.

I'm not asking if it is or isn't fake or modified; I'm trying to simply understand what makes it so... not-quite photographic-looking.

It reminds me of the 1950's SciFi movies where one thing is superimposed on another, pre-green screen.

[image]
(click for full size)

> Vulnerable short-tailed albatross (Phoebastria albatrus) nest in Japan and are responding to protection measures in Japan, Canada and the USA. PHOTO: ©TUI DE ROY/MINDEN PICTURES/CORBIS

This photo can also be found at https://animalsandearth.com/featured/short-tailed-albatross-trio-at-nest-tui-de-roy.html

Comment: I may need some help with tagging; I added the [photoshop] tag as a [proprietary eponym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) because I can't find a suitable version of [modification], nor could I find anything like a [photorealism] or [mixed-media] tag.

Comment: Just looks like lucky with the lighting

Comment: @blobbymcblobby [lighting strikes twice](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87091/50110) (see what I did there?)

Comment: I think it's a studio lamp or a fast moving cloud, so that there was shade on the rocks behind the birds, but the grass is in full sunshine. The clouds seem to have a similar lighting angle, but tthey are in soft shade, the sun should be making those clouds white. it can happen on cloudy days to have a dark sky and a small patch of light on a subject.

Comment: It actually looks like a combination of things, flash fill light, over sharpening of edges via software, lasso and erase and also some hand drawing. It's fairly common practice unfortunately! Most likely, the photographer just processed and submitted. There are other pics similar to this. I am guilty of all this at times too. Bet he never expected for his image to be scrutinised by a bunch of photography geeks! 

Comment: Search for other albatross images. It seems they have very smooth feathers which looks like lassoed.

Answer (score 24):

IMO, the primary cause of the effect is differential lighting. The birds and grass have hard bright frontal light from high right. Whereas the foreground and background appear to have softer/dimmer lighting with less directionality. This can happen naturally; but when the lighting doesn't match it can seem like the images were taken in different places or at different times. Many people will notice this subliminally; and it is one of the major clues that an image has been edited without enough attention to the details.

And the fact that there is not much detail in the birds, where you would kind of expect there to be detail, gives the impression that they could be fake. Especially since there appears to be more detail in the grass and foreground. This is also a characteristic of flat/frontal lighting and monotone colors (e.g. white feathers)... the light fills in all shadows; and without shadows there is no texture/detail visible. The smaller the details (shadows) are, the more likely they are to be filled in.

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph: I think it is the lack of detail in the birds combined with their over-sharpened and very contrast contour.

Answer (score 21):

*Late addition*
To me, the jury's still out on whether it's fake, but I do come down on the side of 'real, but worked up [too] hard'.
In the photographer's defense, I do get the feeling the guy only got one shot [or batch of shots off an auto-trigger] & the camera got the light wrong. It's borderline over-exposed, losing detail from the lighter areas. I've done that myself often with white bird, dark background, your backdrop looks great, bird is sharp… but little feather detail left. So here, heavy cloud, sun peeks through, auto-exposure goes to hell.

In post from a RAW [idk about other cameras but] Nikon has a 'highlight protect' option that attempts to pull back some detail where it's *nearly* gone. It's pretty good at it, better than anything else I've tried, but it's not a miracle worker.

Maybe it was the only frame where they were posed, and not back of head, yawning, scratching under wing, crapping on grass, squabbling… that mars many a wildlife shot.

I also think it's slightly back-focussed. It's hard to tell after so much post on it, but I think the birds' breasts are closer than 'sharp', making the white feather issue even harder to try fix.

---

It looks like it may have had a bit of HDR done to it, to balance up the lighting. This often produces a bit of a halo around sharp edges where there was a lot of change in the light levels.

[image]

It can give a bit of an 'uncanny valley' look to things - in this case it almost looks like studio lighting, which in other circumstances I'd put down to something like Apple's 'portrait mode' which can do that in-camera.

See also: [Halo in pictures taken with HDR](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129985/halo-in-pictures-taken-with-hdr)

Checking a higher res preview from the linked origin, this looks even more like aggressive over-processing more common to a phone. It looks like as well as being HDR'd, it's been aggressively sharpened & de-noised, which gives a very 'plastic' look to things.

[image]

An example of this over-sharpen, over-de-noise effect.
First the original - small crop of a photo taken from too far away for the lens/camera to really cope, so it's noisy & not properly sharp.

[image]

After massive over-processing

[image]

Comment: It's exactly this for me. It looks like the birds are photoshopped into the picture because the edges are unnaturally sharp.

Comment: Aggressive overprocessing seems to be a common complaint with iPhones ever since the iPhone 12 came out.

Comment: I don't think it's fake, the feet are too well integrated into the grass

Answer (score 16):

Complementing Steven Kersting´s answer:

The photo looks like a diorama.

Look at the images at [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=natural%20history%20diorama&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLzInU_ayAAxVlIUQIHXuyCyoQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1835&bih=684&dpr=1.4)

[image]

You put some stuffed animals with a printed photograph as a background, then you add some spotlights.

This happens when you add a flash to a photo taken with a natural light background. It is a really cool effect for portraits.

I feel that the photographer used a flash on a really cloudy day. I think the shadows are not parallel.

[image]

It can also happen when there are stormy clouds in the background and some clear sky in the front. It is not the case in this image because you can see a few clouds; they are oddly dark.

Assuming both the birds and the clouds are white, and illuminated by the same Sun (not on Tatooine) they should look similar in brightness.

Comment: Yes *exactly!* That is just what it's reminding me of; all those natural history museums I was taken to as a kid  a million years ago...

Comment: Interesting that most of the other answers focused on pixel peep.

Answer (score 7):

The very sharp edges of the birds that totally lack loose feathers are indeed surprising. But if you go to the site and check the close-ups, you see some lose feathers on the back of the head of the left bird. In fact the answer is on the head of the middle bird, that shows a halo:

[image]

... which means that at least some parts of the image have been overly sharpened, while the picture isn't that sharp to begin with (check the plumages).

Comment: Original pic probably had a white sky, I guess the editor lassoed the sky and made it blue (or used some sky fixing software)

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you are seeing the same as I, but I agree, that the image at at least on a first glance looks odd.

What I believe confuses my brain is that the birds all have a much brighter front (especially front of neck and breast) than the rest of their plumage. That gives the impression that all birds are lit from the front, although they face in different directions and that the light seemingly used to illuminate the birds does not match the direction of the shadows the birds are throwing on the ground.

Answer (score 5):

#### The birds have "built-in" shading.

I think this is a very important point, and I haven't seen it mentioned yet.

The gradual transition between dark and light feathers can look like it is caused by lighting and not by the natural, ingrained colors of the birds. The shading makes it look like the birds are grouped around a very bright, omnidirectional light source. Of course this light source doesn't exist, which I think makes it hard for our brains to make sense of.

Comment: Albatrosses in general have a lot of really interesting variations on this, half of them look like they put a lot of effort into their eyeshadow every morning (eg https://markavery.info/2019/07/06/tim-melling-black-browed-albatross/)

Comment: @llama beautiful! Now I want to see an albatross, so I googled "Taiwan albatross" and found they aren't very accessible to the public :-)

Comment: @MaxD yes now that you mention it, it really does look like that to me as well.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there are two primary causes of the uncanny valley feel:

- The very smooth silhouette of the three birds, which makes it look like their feathers are only textures on smooth surfaces.
- The fairly uniform and bright reflected light on the underside of the birds looks like the "[ambient lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading#Ambient_lighting)" effect used in real time graphics to inexpensively emulate indirect lighting. In particular, the undersides of the birds are brighter than the shadows cast by the same birds, which is an unusual phenomenon in real life, but less unusual in computer graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Two main reasons

This photograph is taken with a very powerful zoom, if you look closely at both the grass directly in front of the birds and the grass directly behind them, both appear out of focus, highlighting the main figure of the birds. Any photograph of an object in an environment taken with a powerful zoom will make the object appear cut out precisely because of the blur of the surrounding elements.

[image]

See *Nature at mega zoom* at [bryanpfeiffer.com](https://bryanpfeiffer.com/photography/nature-at-mega-zoom/)

Secondly, the characteristic of the photographed object, in particular both the plumage and the shadow of the grass, form a dark outline, better defining the figure.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Link added with more info

Comment: A long lens will appear to 'compress' the distances, but won't provide the halo or over sharpen/denoise.

Comment: That's true. JPG artifact?

Comment: No. The original photo still shows the halo. It's all just been massively over-processed. To be fair to the photographer, if you only get one shot at something like this, you're gonna try your best to make it useable ;)

Comment: If you look at the photos of the link that I put in the question, you can see the halo in some, for example in the lower part of the seagull

Comment: Yup, as already noted. The halo, though, is not an artefact of the camera/lens, but of post processing. Here's one I shot on a very long lens, no halo [because no HDR processing] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YDUY.jpg - assuming you like squirrels ;)) tbh, I don't think the OP's photo is on a particularly long lens, the DoF's not all that short.

Comment: I believe more in light refraction in the part of the sky, the albatross on the left does not have a halo in the part that appears on the grass.

Comment: That's because there was less lighting difference in that area in the original. You're only going to see refraction on a truly sharp edge & also usually when backlit. I don't think that's satisfactory explanation for that shot.

Comment: To me it still looks like the out-of-focus flowers in the foreground and the out-of-focus dry grass in the extreme upper left are both close to  (say +/- 1 meter), but on either side of the birds, and that the camera may have also been close and have a narrow depth of focus, rather than the results of the "very powerful zoom". I'm still thinking camouflaged, automatic scientific wildlife camera. But I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll post a question with sample photos (when I have time ) to see what kind of answers we get

Answer (score 2):

To substantiate earlier answers *on perception* of the true color image, one complement the analysis with *image statistics* as a tool less prone to personal bias.

This attempts a synthesis of the contribution by the answers by @Tetsujin (because of the provision of a prior/after processing illustration) in comparison to the one of the squirrel (answer by @Danielillo) and the [preview](https://animalsandearth.com/featured/short-tailed-albatross-trio-at-nest-tui-de-roy.html) of your question.

Art aside, photography equally is a measurement; and every measurement has some random error. Inconsistencies in processing (electronic) photos can yield a non-uniform error level across a JPEG image which *as such* can be visualized like a map.  One of the programs accessible to the public I'm aware of is [forensically](https://29a.ch/photo-forensics/#error-level-analysis) by Jonas Wagner created around 2012 ([blog post](https://29a.ch/2015/08/16/forensically-photo-forensics-for-the-web), and [12 min youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRCq8CJrI_s); both in English).

Let's submit the two versions of the bird image by @Tetsujin to perform an *Error Level Analysis*. To highlight the differences, an alternating gif of the two annotated illustrations:

[image]

(analysis based on the .png files shared, *vide infra*)

The differences might be subtle: watch the areas of patches of similar (false) color which tend to be more uniform for the smoothed illustration.  For training purpose the same was applied on the portrait of the squirrel.  We observe two level of noise here: the background, on one hand *vs.* animal and tree on the other.  This is easy to comprehend by the use of a tele lens; here, used to «get close enough» (and in classical portrait photography, to separate the object from the less interesting background which should not distract too much from the former).

[image]

(based on the .png shared in the answer)

[image]

(based on the .jpg from the author's web page [here](https://bryanpfeiffer.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/wa-douglas-squirrel-zoom-1440.jpg))

The comparison shows that the file format can influence the result of this analysis (after all, .png are more suitable for screen photos anyway).

And eventually, the albatross.  Bodies and necks, but not (so much) the feet clearly stand out this much in comparison to the surrounding grass that a high level of editing is likely.  And the sky in the background.

[image]

(based on the .jpg of the preview [here](https://animalsandearth.com/featured/short-tailed-albatross-trio-at-nest-tui-de-roy.html)).

The similar tool [fakeimagedetector](https://www.fakeimagedetector.com/) offers a slider to show the true color image/false color representation of the noise map.  After some time, you can't unsee the variation in coarseness in the later.

[image]

(screenphoto from https://www.fakeimagedetector.com/)

*Addition*

There are multiple types of errors which add up to noise in the image.

- photon shot noise: light is both wave and particle, but the arrival of photons on the detector is noncontinuous and random.  The emission of photons need not be homogeneous across a surface area inspected, either.
- electronic noise of the readout: recording an image is assigning a pixel an intensity value.  To obtain a larger number of charges per pixel eventually easier to process, this amplification may introduce an error.(1)
- quantization noise of the readout: the (amplified) analog signal is converted into a digital one.  (Your analog signal may end up in the wrong digital bin.)

Aside from these, the pixels within a camera chip are not uniform; right from production, some may be less sensitive, than others.  Repeated overexposure/too high levels of gain (especially ICCD camera), etc. may lead to dead pixels no longer recording a signal.  Second, a pixel in operation can report intensity even in absence of a radiation source adding dark current noise.  This however is more relevant to intentional observation of dim scenes / experiments with an
extended period of exposure (e.g., fluorescence microscopy, astrophotography, X-ray crystallography) where one intentionally awaits temperature stabilization of the area detector, and collects dark frames for a subsequent background collection on individual frames.  See (3) the above paraphrases.

These influences are all ahead of storing the information as .csv, [.pgm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PGM_example), plain/LZW compressed .tiff.  Or before the camera equally corrects white balance,
adjusts sharpness, starts other electronic/AI filters (modern cellular phones) and applies a lossy compression like JPEG for the file available for you.(4)  Subsequent edits on JPEGs require to encode parts of the retouched areas which then distort the file further, this and the transitions is spot by the program.

footnotes:

(1) With ICCD cameras,(2) this gain actually can be adjusted and can introduce additional problems down the road (leaving the linear range / where recorded signal is proportional to the intensity).

(2) Without particular endorsement, e.g. [LaVision](https://www.lavision.de/en/products/cameras/intensified-cameras/).

(3) Youtube videos [Microscopy: Cameras and Detectors I: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WpCov8iYCU) and [Microscopy: Cameras and Detectors II: Specifications and Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzhhGHxP-Jc) by Nico Stuurman as
part of a whole [class](https://www.ibiology.org/online-biology-courses/microscopy-series/) around light microscopy and relevant image processing.

(4) [How are Images Compressed?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kv1Hiv3ox8I) by BranchEducation is an instructive video about the steps of JPEG compression (color space conversion, chrominance downsampling, discrete coside transform, quantization the eventual Huffman encoding). It both explains the steps, and one gets an idea why recording a photo in a raw format rather than JPEG can be advantageous.  (Not every image format constrains the  the intensity depth to 8 bit per (color) channel (i.e., 256 levels) only.)

Comment: What does "error" mean here? how is error measured without some sort of ground truth image?

Comment: @Vaelus this is image statistics - Buttonwood can answer more accurately, but it's something like the difference between a pixel's value and perhaps the average of the four adjacent pixels. Smooth gradients will be nearly zero, hot pixels will be super bright, and the ever-present noise ([shot noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise) and other effects) will result in the "snow" we see in these images. You might imagine this being an ultra-high frequency high-pass filter.

Comment: @Vaelus images from different sources will often have different noise levels so if they are both present in one combined image they'll stand out in a noise image.

Comment: @Buttonwood sorry for my inexact explanation above please correct me if I'm wrong. But I have a question; during the inevitable photo tweaking and processing someone might do to make it look "better" various processing filters are applied. If just for arguments sake a sigmoid or erf() function is used which adds contrast at lower intensities by substantially flattening out at the high end, would that not also result in lower noise in the large "white" areas on the birds. There's plenty of noise on the darker parts of their heads and their beaks. Perhaps I'm not fully understanding? (+1 btw!)

Comment: @Buttonwood **update:** *Oh! I see.* For example the side of the albatross on the right transitions from near white to near black and is *everywhere less noisy*. Ya that really stands out! https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgqMj.jpg I suppose the routine that converts images to JPEGs might recognize the albatross area as a lower gradient region, and in the interest of compression might restrict conversion of those areas to only lower order wavelets (or whatever functions JPEG uses) thus resulting in lower "noise".

Comment: @Vaelus It is a good point what "error" in an "error level analysis" of an image refers to.  There is an additional section to the answer now.

Comment: @uhoh I complemented the answer with a section what typical errors in an image (statistically speaking) can be, and some references. Because of some previous exchanges with you more related to crystallography, some of them might be equally of interest there (e.g., slowly sweeping $\phi$ on a single crystal X-ray diffractometre, recording with a CCD [instead of a point detector], and even more, with an image plate), too.

Comment: @Buttonwood I'm following your post and I find it really interesting, and now with the edit I'll start again and go through carefully and check all your links, it demands no less! *Thanks for pursuing this so thoroughly!* In another life [I also looked at long exposure photographic plates of the stars :-)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43357/7982) We never got out the dry ice to reduce reciprocity failure, but we had some fun!

Answer (score 1):

Note really an answer perhaps, more of an opinion:

For me it seems like the theres a lot of fuss over not very much.

Yes, there is much pixel peeping at edges, level of sharpening used, but I do not think that that was defining it as 'looking fake'. Sure, the processing looks like a lot on close inspection but I do not think that that 'is it' in terms of whats going on, if anything is...

Its simply the brightness of the birds against the duller background that is making people think it is not an entirely natural image. But I've seen, or even taken images that have given that effect before, usually unintentionally, and usually in natural lighting conditions where the sun pokes through on a not entirely sunny day and the subjects are bright anyway.

I think someone else did touch on it - the plumage of the birds are somewhat naturally luminous, and catch available light in a very broad way:

[image]

I do think the shadows and lighting match the birds self shadow and the fall on the ground

[image]

There is bright sunlight, it is falling on everything in the frame, the background and the birds.

Perhaps there is expectation that the dark plumage would also go bright with the fall of sunlight on it and I think the plumage does not do that, it retains its darkness.

Due to the natural brightness picked up on the birds, it is this area that looks a little too bright for people, and that is where the suggestion of an artificial light comes in, but i would argue against that, not last because using an artificial light is not a great idea with bird wildlife photography - i thin kit would be frowned upon in such circles, and the photographer has done a fair bit of bird photography. Flash is even less likely, as is a reflector - none of those ideas really match what is going on here, which is that the photographer was lucky in picking right time, place, and lens for the frame.

Coming from another angle, i have a background in 3d cgi as well, and to get that look in basic surfacing, we would modify fall off, making it broad, and probably adjusting certain bounce/diffuse maps and colors of the birds - all of which would produce a brighter, broader lit, bird, without adding an additional light - the sun is enough.

*What makes it look unnatural?*

A combination of lighting conditions at the time, direction, place, and lens, and the birds plumage,, against the background, is what makes them look superimposed. Yes, there is probably a bit of an issue with aggressive post processing, but I do not believe that this is the singular issue that is creating an issue.